# Altering order and names of data-frame by row in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data-frame which looks like the following:

```
> DisintegrationBehavior
             gden    degree
1.txt  0.45000000 0.7083333
14.txt 0.58333333 0.5000000
11.txt 0.50000000 0.4166667
12.txt 0.50000000 0.6666667
13.txt 0.25000000 0.5000000
```

I would like to remove the .txt from the row names, then add "team" in front of every row number, and then order the results by the row number (or whichever order is easier) so that the final result looks like:

```
> DisintegrationBehavior
             gden    degree
team1  0.45000000 0.7083333
team11 0.50000000 0.4166667
team12 0.50000000 0.6666667
team13 0.25000000 0.5000000
team14 0.58333333 0.5000000
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
s <- sub(".txt", "", rownames(df), fixed = TRUE)
rownames(df) <- paste0("team", s)
df[order(as.numeric(s)), ]
#             gden    degree
# team1  0.4500000 0.7083333
# team11 0.5000000 0.4166667
# team12 0.5000000 0.6666667
# team13 0.2500000 0.5000000
# team14 0.5833333 0.5000000
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(gden = c(0.45, 0.58333333, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25), degree = c(0.7083333, 
0.5, 0.4166667, 0.6666667, 0.5)), .Names = c("gden", "degree"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1.txt", "14.txt", "11.txt", 
"12.txt", "13.txt"))
```

Comment: This works except for the last line as it is ordering them by the digit in the tens place so I am getting this `team1          0.45000000
team11         0.50000000
team12         0.50000000
team13         0.25000000
team14         0.58333333
team15         0.58333333
team16         0.83333333
team17         0.70000000
team18         0.50000000
team19         0.75000000
team2          0.70000000
team20         0.66666667`  How could I do it so it orders them by the overall number instead of just the 10s digit?  Thank you!